How to pass query parameters to login page
I have an ASP.NET Core Minimal API with cookie authentication and I need to add some query parameters to login url when redirecting user to login page, so I can show user some hint on the login page.
I have authorize endpoint that checks if the user is logged in and if not, it returns ChallengeResult with some custom parameters. However somehow the user is not redirected and only blank page is shown (with authorize endpoint url).
Here is my startup configuration:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/login";
        options.LogoutPath = "/logout";
        options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
        {
            OnRedirectToLogin = ctx =>
            {
                ctx.Options.LoginPath = $"/login?hint={ctx.Properties.Parameters["hint"]}";
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });

And here is my authorize endpoint with challenge result:
builder.MapGet("/authorize", HttpContext httpcontext)
{
   if(!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
   {
       var props = new AuthenticationProperties
                  {
                       RedirectUri = "my/redirect/url",
                       Parameters = {{"hint", "someHint"}},    
                  };
       return Results.Challenge(props, [CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme]);
   } else {...}
}

From debugging, I can see that OnRedirectToLogin method is hit, the LoginPath is overwritten, but that is all, the browser does not get redirected.

If the user is NOT authenticated, should you not be calling await HttpContext.SignInAsync() with an appropriate redirect? See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Well I dont think so, HttpContext.SignInAsync() is for signing the user in and one of the parameters of this method is ClaimsPrincipal, but in my authorize endpoint I cant create ClaimsPrincipal, I dont have user, because the user is NOT authenticated, as you said. I need to Challenge him to go to login page, provide credentials, SignIn him in my another Login endpoint and return to this Authorize endpoint.

I see, then can you not just issue a LocalRedirect to your Login endpoint rather than issuing a Challenge?

You sir are a genius. That should do the trick. Why did not I think about that in the first place? Anyway, thank you!
